# How to test IOPS on Windows?

Tags: windows, hard-disk

I need a software to test I/O Operation per Second under Windows. It's preferable if it runs under XP and can test network drives.

Answer (score 1):

[SQLIO Disk Subsystem Benchmark Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20163)

> SQLIO is a tool provided by Microsoft which can also be used to determine the I/O capacity of a given configuration.

Despite the name, you do not need an SQL server to use the tool.

Comment: As of end of 2015 SQLIO has been replaced by DiskSpd: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/DiskSpd-a-robust-storage-6cd2f223